# Custom powershell backgroundcolor reverts when running commands?

Tags: powershell, colors, console

I'm using a powershell profile to change the background color of the powershell console (to black) when its running as my superuser account, or based on other criteria. I do this simply by setting the following variables in my profile ps1.

```
$host.ui.rawui.backgroundcolor = "black"
$host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = "white"
```

Console windows using this profile open with a black background, and the initial prompt is white text with a black background. Hitting `Enter` without typing anything doesn't change this.

However as soon as I enter any text whatsoever, the background color of the typed text, the prompts, and any output (except for errors) reverts to being the default white on navy blue. The overall console background remains black.

Reloading the profile with `. .\path\profile.ps1` or manually resetting the `$host` variables (as above) reverts the prompt to white on black, but the same behavior happens again. The most bizarre thing is that even typing text then backspacing it and entering nothing still causes the prompt to revert to navy.

Is there any way to *actually* have a pure black background, or is this just a limitation of the powershell console (v5.1 btw)?

I've seen some references to other color-related variables, but I don't see how they are helpful in this regard:

```
$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor
$host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor
$host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor
$host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor
$host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor
$host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor
$host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor
$host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor
$host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor
$host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor
```

P.S. I'd post an image, but my prompt and stuff has personal info in it. I sure can't wait for the fancy new Terminal MS announced last month. I can only hope it's far less cumbersome than this.

Comment: Did you want EVERY word in your command line to be white? or just a black background for all command line?

Comment: @Drew The idea was to make it look more or less like a traditional command prompt window. Black overall background, and white text with black background. But only in certain conditions, such that I have easy visual cues. Seems like the $host variables are just not enough to accomplish that without the help of the inflexible GUI-based color preference settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your `PSReadLineOption` options accordingly as well as the `RawUI` and `PrivateData`.

See `Get-PSReadlineOption` to find the current colours and what adjusts them with `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind $token -BackgroundColor Black`

Comment: Holy cow, there's all those options! Thanks a lot. I would have never found that. It's an extremely difficult thing to google without any previous knowledge :P

Comment: FWIW, PSReadLineOption has changed in v2 (Powershell v6 and/or 1809+). The `-TokenKind` parameter is no longer available, and colors are set via a hashtable sent to the `-Colors` parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6

Comment: I think you mean V6. V5.1 still has it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Strange, I'm using 5.1 on 1809 and it's not recognized.

Comment: Ah I found where I got the info from again: It's in a closed feedback thread on the 5.1 doc. PSReadLineOption V2 ships with both Powershell v6 AND with later versions of Win10: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/3371#issuecomment-443799484 The new version seems to make it a hell of a lot more complicated to do background colors, but apparently it's possible.

Comment: Aha, found a great post explaining how the escape color codes work: http://jafrog.com/2013/11/23/colors-in-terminal.html